# How to get the different types of errors from a Persistence Exception in JPA?

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, jpa, eclipselink

How can i discriminate the error that caused the exception? I want to make different things based on the type of error i get. Something like this:

```java
try {

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    entityManager.persist(entity);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

} catch (PersistenceException exception) {

    if(DUPLICATE_RECORD)
        //do something about it
    else if(SOME_VALUE_IS_NULL)
        //do something about it
    else if(SOME_VALUE_IS_OUT_OF_RANGE) 
        //do something about it
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PersistenceException` has sub-classes which you can catch separately, such as :

- EntityExistsException
- EntityNotFoundException
- NonUniqueResultException
- NoResultException
- OptimisticLockException
- RollbackException
- TransactionRequiredException

Catch whichever one of them you care about separately, before catching `PersistenceException`.

For example :

```
try {
    ....
} 
catch (EntityExistsException exception) {
    ....
}
catch (PersistenceException exception) {
    .... 
}
```

`EntityExistsException` is probably the exception you want to catch to find out when the object you try to persist already exists :

> Thrown by the persistence provider when EntityManager.persist(Object) is called and the entity already exists.

Comment: Ok, that is great, i will use it. But i have a doubt, how can you catch a exception thrown by a trigger in the database?

Comment: @ivan0590 That's a separate question, to which I don't know the answer.

Comment: Ok, i will make a new question then. Thanks a lot for helping a newbie like me ;)